# How to query database on boot?

Tags: swift, vapor

I'm trying to schedule the query of a random element every minute in my database.

The schedule part works but I don't find a way to pick an item from the database...

I'm a swift beginner. Maybe I missed something important !

Let me know if you need more informations

This is my code from boot.swift

```
import Fluent
import FluentSQLite

func foo(on container: Container) {
    let future = container.withPooledConnection(to: .sqlite) { db in
        return Future.map(on: container){ }
    }
    future.do{ msg in

        let allQuotes = QuoteOfTheDay.query(on: ).all().wait()
        quoteOfTheDay = allQuotes.randomElement()

        }.catch{ error in
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

/// Called after your application has initialized.
public func boot(_ app: Application) throws {
    // your code here

    func runRepeatTimer() {

        app.eventLoop.scheduleTask(in: TimeAmount.minutes(1), runRepeatTimer)
        foo(on: app)
    }

    runRepeatTimer()

}
```

Comment: I don't have a solid answer for you. But have you tried asking your question on the Vapor discord app?  I would also suggest using `scheduleRepeatedTask`.  Also I don't know what you're trying to achieve by getting a quoteOfTheDay every minute. Maybe a question about what you're trying to achieve in general instead of what operation you're trying to do could help better solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I choose every minutes for the test so I can show if it works. But what I want is every 24 hours. What I want is to create a backend site on which I can add many quotes and an API which return every 24h a new quote for an another site on which I used .getJSON from jquery. Does it make sense ?

Comment: Is your service going to PUSH a new quote to each client? For this you need some mechanism like web sockets. I don't think this is all that necessary. Your service should simply trigger every 1 day, pick a new quote from the database, set it somewhere (maybe redis or in your database) then go to sleep (or die). You can initially let someone do this manually every day. Now each new client that requests the latest quote will get the one set as being current. The point is that picking a quote and returning the current quote are 2 completely different things so treat them as separate services.

Comment: You can even do this lazily.  A client requests the current quote.  You grab the current quite from the database (or redis). Your service checks its date, and realize its older than 1 day. So you generate a new one set it as current in the database (or redis) than return that. The point here is that you don't have a running task, getting the latest quite is triggered at the time of a new request. Ultimately you can let picking be done by a separate service but since you are learning focus on simplicity first.

Comment: Ok I see. I will try this. In fact, it's seems to be much simpler and more logical. Thanks for your advice :)

Answer (score 1):

`Application` conforms to `Container` so you can call it in `boot(_:)` and just provider the application

Comment: Thank you but I didn't understand how to adapt my code to your answer... what could be the right code in my case ?

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood the question! What you should do is something like `return container.withPooledConnection()` future. In there you can then get your connection and do `QuoteOfTheDay(on: conn).query(...)` - does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, you can query items from you database at boot time through :

```
          let req = Request(using: app)
          let allQuotes = QuoteOfTheDay.query(on: req).all().wait()
          quoteOfTheDay = allQuotes.randomElement()
```

Also, for repeated task every 24H you can use.

```
          app.eventLoop.scheduleRepeatedTask(initialDelay: TimeAmount.seconds(0), delay: TimeAmount.hours(24), foo(on: app))
```